# My C++ program cannot open named pipe

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, named-pipes

I am trying to run C++ application that works perfectly on Mac OS under Ubuntu. The problem is due to failure in opening a named pipe.

I used `mkfifo` as follows:

```
  pipe_name_ = std::string("/tmp/myfifo");
  if (mkfifo(pipe_name_.c_str(), 0666) < 0) {
     error_print("Cannot create a named pipe\n");
     return -1;
  }

  if ((fd_ = open(pipe_name_.c_str(), O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)) < 0) {
     error_print("Cannot open file description named %s %s\n",
                 pipe_name_.c_str(), strerror(errno));
     return -1;
  }
```

However, this prints into screen the bellow message that is for `open()`:

`Cannot open file description named /tmp/myfifo Invalid argument`

My permissions status is as bellow:

```
$ls -la /tmp/myfifo
prw-r----- 1 hamidb nonconf 0 Jun 20 13:35 /tmp/myfifo
$umask
0027
```

I am wondering why it was working fine on Mac OS and not on Linux.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  You say both..

Comment: When `open` (or other system calls) fail check `errno` to see what the error was. Use e.g. `strerror` to get a printable string of the error.

Comment: I am using c++ to compile

Comment: I am not sure if you can create a file if dont have the write flag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It says `Invalid argument`

Comment: @VTT What should it be instead?

Comment: There's something you're not telling us... [The manual page for `open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) states that using the wrong flags will result in `EINVAL` (the error you get), and you *do* use the wrong flags. Lastly, if it would have worked then the `open` call would have *blocked* until there was a writer opening the pipe (which happens with my simple testing, even with the wrong flags!) In short, it's time you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You were right. I had redefined the O_ flags somewhere in my code.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you have the wrong flags for `open` as you are not creating the file.

It should be

```
open(pipe_name_.c_str(), O_RDONLY)
```

Comment: That was not the issue.